# How to draw a line (1D) with labeled subdivisions

Tags: graphics

I want to draw a simple line with some symbols, but so far have had no luck finding an easy way to do it in *Mathematica*. Does anyone know if *Mathematica* can easily implement e.g. the example below?

[image: example]

Comment: Try [`NumberLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberLinePlot.html) in *Mathematica 10*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to show some basics using `Text`, and `Line`:

```
text[s_String, s1_String, pos_] := {Text[s, {pos, .04}], Text[s1, {pos, -.04}]}
tick[pos_] := Line[{{pos, .01}, {pos, -.01}}]
Show[Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}],
 Graphics[{
   text["", "0", 0], 
   text["σ2(m1)", "x/2", 1/4], 
   text["", "x/2+1/4", 2/4], 
   text["σ2(m2)", "x/2+1/2", 3/4],
   text["", "1", 1], 
   tick /@ Range[0, 1, 1/4]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea of what direction to go, try this:

```
 Show[{
  Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}], 
    AbsoluteThickness[1], 
    Line[{Scaled[{0.25, 0.45}], Scaled[{0.25, 0.55}]}], 
    Line[{Scaled[{0.75, 0.45}], Scaled[{0.75, 0.55}]}]}],
  Graphics[{Text[
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \
\(2\)]\)(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(1\)]\))", 12], 
     Scaled[{0.25, 0.8}]], 
    Text[Style[
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \
\(2\)]\)(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\))", 12], 
     Scaled[{0.75, 0.8}]]}]

  }]
```

which looks like this

[image]

Other elements you may draw by analogy. Have fun!

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much!